# How to pipe output of ffmpeg to three different processes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg

How can I pipe output of ffmpeg without saving it to a file to three different processes?

Let's say I have:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg output.yuv
```

I would like to change that in order to avoid saving YUV to physical disk. I would like to pipe it to three different shell commands.

How to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Set `ffmpeg`'s output to standard out by specifying `-` as the output file, and then use `tee` and process substitution:

```
ffmpeg ... - | tee >(command1) >(command2) >(command3)
```

Be sure to specify the format using `-f` as `ffmpeg` won't be able to guess it based on the output filename.

Comment: `tee` will also write a copy to stdout so unless you want 4 copies `>(command3)` should be `| command3`.

Comment: @mark4o: That way, you would send output of command1 and command2 (if any) to command3 as well.